# Cохранить от пользователя несколько значений

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Как сохранить от пользователя числа введенные через пробел?
Надо что бы в этой строчке `btn1 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите числа через пробел')`
сохранить и в будущем вывести все числа.

Как я понял надо преобразовать эту строчку **chisla = int(message.text)**

```
import telebot

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("token")

@ bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def start(message):

    btn1 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите числа через пробел')

    bot.register_next_step_handler(btn1, sum)

def sum(message):

    chisla = int(message.text)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Вы ввели {chisla}')

bot.polling(non_stop = True)
```

Comment: скорее всего вам нужно вот это `chisla = map(int, message.text.split())`

Comment: @turkindv выводится почему-то только первое число

Comment: а добавьте `print(message.text)` что бы посмотреть приходит ли все сообщение от пользователя и что именно приходит и напишите сюда

Comment: @turkindv в боте только 1,

в pythone 
C:\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Python/Work/eras_test_bot.py
1 2 3 4 5

Comment: хм, это странно что только одно число, но возможно проблема из за того что map возвращает ссылку, а не результат
попробуйте еще так `chisla = list(map(int, message.text.split()))`

Comment: @turkindv также . очень странно

Answer (score 0):

как пример

```
message = '1 2 3 4 5'

chisla = list(map(int, message.split()))
#или
#chisla = [int(x) for x in message.split()]
print('Вы ввели', ','.join(map(str, chisla)))
#или
#print('Вы ввели', ','.join([str(x) for x in chisla]))
print('Сумма всех чисел', sum(chisla))

Вы ввели 1,2,3,4,5
Сумма всех чисел 15
```

Comment: Как теперь это в бота запихнуть? в строчке chisla = int(message.text) он выводит только первое число

Answer (score 0):

мне показалось это очень странным и я запустил его самостоятельно c изменениями которые писал в комментариях и все работает

```py
import telebot

token = "token"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):

    btn1 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите числа через пробел')

    bot.register_next_step_handler(btn1, sum)


def sum(message):

    chisla = list(map(int, message.text.split()))

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Вы ввели {chisla}')

bot.polling(non_stop = True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень странно, спасибо!)